# Mobile user and Geolocation

Tags: android, database-design, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-geolocation

I have seen many websites that have tutorials on getting the Geolocation of a device and displaying it on a map.

However, I'm looking to get the geolocation of the users mobile device then pushing that to a database (need help on this)

and then displaying multiple users on a single map.

Essentially I'm trying to make the client side of the Uber/sidecar app where I could see different cars position in real time.

Any tutorials that would be helpful?

Comment: you are using Android, just get the lat, long pair, make a server side api (Php, java, .net any), send data to it, save to db, and show it on google maps    
1. Get the location - https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
2. Rest API - http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/
3. Show points on google map - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: anything to read about making a serverside api and saving to database?

Comment: Read the link, it is saving the data to database